# How do I keep a stream open from model to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am editing a pdf then print in a new tab. I am getting an error saying I "Cannot access a closed stream." This is what I have thus far...

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult QST(string ID) 
{   
    ...
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/Content/PDF/QST.pdf"));
    QstRepository repo = new QstRepository();
    Stream newPdf = repo.GS(ID, reader);            
    return new FileStreamResult(newPdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

MODEL

```
public Stream GS(string ID, PdfReader reader)
{
    Stream newPdf = new MemoryStream();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfStamper formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
        AcroFields formFields = formFiller.AcroFields;
        formFields.SetField("ID", ID);

        formFiller.FormFlattening = true;
        formFiller.Writer.CloseStream = false;
        newPdf = ms;
        formFiller.Close();
    }
    return newPdf;
}
```

How do I access the pdf before it is closed... or how do I access the pdf after?

Answer (score 3):

The last two lines of your code before you return are

```
newPdf = ms;
formFiller.Close();
```

Since your code is all within a `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())` block, the `MemoryStream` ms will be closed before you return anyway.

Since you are assigning `newPdf` to the variable `ms`, nwePdf eventualy returns the same (already closed) `MemoryStream` that `ms` points to.

You could have `public Stream GS(string ID, PdfReader reader)` just create the stream without the using block, but then you run the risk of it staying open if an exception occurs in your code.  I suppose you could try the following:

```
// All calls to GS() must ensure that the returned stream gets closed.
public Stream GS(string ID, PdfReader reader) 
{ 
    MemoryStream newPdf = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper formFiller = null;
    try 
    { 
        formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, newPdf); 
        AcroFields formFields = formFiller.AcroFields; 
        formFields.SetField("ID", ID); 

        formFiller.FormFlattening = true;
        //formFiller.Writer.CloseStream = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        // Only close newPdf on an exception
        newPdf.Close();
        throw; // Rethrow original exception
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always ensure that formFiller gets closed
        formFiller.Close();
    }
    return newPdf; 
}
```

**Update:** I removed the extra MemoryStream, since the one was simply being declared at the beginning of the function, and then set to point to the other at the end, without ever being used for anything else in between.

**Update:** I found an [example using the PdfStamper](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/6623/dynamically-generating-pdfs-in-net/).  According to the example, calling formFiller.Close() is what actually writes to the stream.  In their example, they do not set the Writer.CloseStream property to false.  That may be why you're getting a blank page.  Unfortunately, I was not able to find any actual documentation on PdfStamper to verify this.

Comment: I am making progress I think. I dont have the error, now I just have a blank new tab...

Comment: I found an article that showed someone doing just what you are trying to do.  In their example, they didn't set `formFiller.Writer.CloseStream` to false.  Try that.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `ms` and `newPdf` refer to the same `MemoryStream` instance; since `ms` is closed at the end of the `using` block, `newPdf` is closed too (since it's the same stream). So you need to return the `Stream` without closing it:

```
public Stream GS(string ID, PdfReader reader)
{
    PdfStamper formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    AcroFields formFields = formFiller.AcroFields;
    formFields.SetField("ID", ID);

    formFiller.FormFlattening = true;
    formFiller.Writer.CloseStream = false;
    formFiller.Close();
    return ms;
}
```

I'm not very familiar with ASP.NET MVC, but I assume that `FileStreamResult` takes care of closing the stream.